# Not able restore mysql database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, restore

When i try to delete `mysql` database, before restoring, getting an error,

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

But the `mysql.proc` exists in the database before dropping database.
Any idea why MySql is behaving unexpectedly here?

> **NOTE**: This is not upgraded database, this is newly installed MariaDb-10.0.26 database.

```
Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| column_stats              |
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| gtid_slave_pos            |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| index_stats               |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| roles_mapping             |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| table_stats               |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> drop database mysql;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

Comment: You do realise that the database called `mysql` is MySQL's own database. A databse of databases if you like. Its what MySQL(mariaDB) uses to know about all the other databases. **The ring to control all other rings** if you like

Comment: And if you are doing a backup and restore to move from one version of MySQL(mariaDB) to another, it should not be one of the old version databases that you backup and restore.

Comment: I want restore from previous  backup of `mysql` taken from same machine. And version was changed from time of backup.

Comment: So restore only YOUR databases, Not MySQL's databses

Comment: Its a software that i am working on, it allows restoring `mysql`. But in this particular machine, its failing with an unexpected error. In other setups its possible to delete and recreate `mysql`.

Comment: What happened when you tried to install over the existing version without first dropping `mysql`?  What version was it?